# IntelliJ doesn't see Selenium Chromedriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea

I am trying to run tests using Selenium on IntelliJ and constantly getting the following error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property;` Here is the example:

```
public class Sample {
 void sampleMethod(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\My\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
        webDriver.get("http://google.com");
        }

}
```

In Eclipse all the tests with Selenium are running, and I do not get this error.

What I have already tried:

1. Adding folder where chromedriver is to PATH;
2. Adding chromedriver to the project and using relative path.
3. Checking the driver is executable.
4. trying to pass the driver path via command line

Seems, that IntelliJ still doesn't see the driver

Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe there is some antivirus that blocks the execution? If it's not the case, please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I checked antivirus, it was not the cause. Actually, I just created a completely new and empty project, added sample code for selenium webdrvier (as in the topic), and actually it worked. Still do not know what was the reason. I moved the code from the previous project to the newly created one, and it also works. Thanks for support

Answer (score 0):

A few minutes ago I exactly had the same issue. The solution was not just to import the libs from the /lib folder, but also die jars from the parent folder. Issue fixed.